# Send SWT token to a generated wcf proxy and validate it

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-security, wcf-client, accesscontrolservice

I've got an WP7 application who does authentication with Azure Access Control Service and stores it's SimpleWebToken in an the IsolatedStorage. I want to use this SWT-token to secure my (locally deployed not in AZURE)WCF Service. (The WCF service is finished, except the ACS token validation part) So I've added an Service Reference in my WP7 application and now I want to send the SWT-token to WCF Service via the generated WCF proxy client, but how? Or is this not the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because custom binding & wsHttpBinding isn't supported on WP7(Not sure if mango fixes this) and I don't want to use a WCFDataService. I've come with an nasty solution, I will add a string(the simplewebtoken) to my operationcontract and send it with every client call. I validate this token in the serviceimplentation with the configured securityTokenHandler. This currently works for me!